# Monotouch UIDatePicker SetDate always 1Hours and 5 Minutes

Tags: xamarin.ios, uidatepicker

I tried to set the initial Date at UIDatePicker in Monotouch. The DatePicker always shows 1:05 in UIDatePickerMode.Time. If I do nothing it shows the current Time correctly.

Anybody can help me how to do this in Monotouch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you setting up your NSDate corre correctly?  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148906/create-nsdate-monotouch) shows two ways to create a NSDate.

```cs
pick = new UIDatePicker (new RectangleF (0, 20, this.View.Bounds.Width, 10));   

// Set NSDate:
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("1981-07-01 22:21:00");
NSDate nsDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(date, DateTimeKind.Utc);

// Get DateTime from NSDate:
date = DateTime.SpecifyKind(nsDate, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
pick.Date = date;
pick.Mode = UIDatePickerMode.Time;
```

Comment: Thank's for answer but i can't get it work.... So i overwrite it in a Methode and add a hour and 5 minutes.

Comment: I do not understand.  What are you trying to set this time to?  Do you want to set it to 1:05?  Can you update your question with a code sample of what you are trying?