# Parse NSDate with format @"MMM dd ''YY"

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, parsing, nsdate

I have a date string which looks like this: **Mar 13 '15**

I am not able to find the right way to parse this. I've tried the following:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MMM dd ''YY"];
//[df setDateFormat:@"MMM dd 'YY"];
//[df setDateFormat:@"MMM dd YY"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:label.text];
```

Does anyone know how to do it using setDateFormat ?
Thanks^^

Comment: try with MMM dd, ''yy instead of MMM dd, ''YY

Comment: Use lowercase yy.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822417/why-cant-i-correctly-parse-this-date-string-with-nsdateformatter.  See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`YY` is for year in week based calendars, which is used in some non-gregorian calendars. You generally should use `yy` instead. See the [unicode reference of valid date pattern](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

And you should set the locale to `en_US_POSIX`, to make sure that the date is parsed as a date in the english language. For example in the german locale your conversion would fail because instead of `Mar 13 '15` today is `März 13 '15`.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MMM dd ''yy"];
[df setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```

Comment: It worked :-). Danke for the detailed answer and the side note on locale. There is a tiny error; it should read **localeWithLocaleIdentifier**.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong style of year, you need to use lowercase y.

```
        [df setDateFormat:@"MMM d ''yy"];
```

Uppercase Y is documented as "Year (in "Week of Year" based calendars)." and mentions "May not always be the same value as calendar year". See:
http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns